# Qt5 Static Build yields Failed to load platform plugin "windows"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt, qt5

I am writing a Qt application on Windows using **Visual Studio 2012**. 
Using the Qt Add-in and a custom built **static** distribution of **Qt 5.0.2**.
I am running into the dreaded `"Failed to load platform plugin windows"` error whenever I run the application.
I have added the following to the linker input:

```
imm32.lib
winmm.lib
Ws2_32.lib
qtmaind.lib
Qt5Cored.lib
Qt5Guid.lib
Qt5Widgetsd.lib
```

At first I thought that maybe I should add "qwindowsd.lib" to that list as well however that did not fix the problem. What do I need to do in order to make my application run?

Comment: use windeployQt

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I solved it. Thanks to [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27037) I was able to get everything to work. I added the following libraries:

```
opengl32.lib
Qt5PlatformSupport.lib
qwindows.lib
```

I also added the following to my code:

```
#include <QtPlugin>
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN (QWindowsIntegrationPlugin);
```

Comment: How did you link qwindows.lib. The normal route of adding LIBS += qwindows.lib didn't find it.

Comment: Also unable to find qwindows.lib anywhere

Comment: @PsychoDad It's only available if you have built the static Qt libraries.  With the normal builds downloaded from the Qt website, you just need to put the qwindows.dll (or qwindowsd.dll) shared library in the **platforms** subfolder next to your built executable. Make this subdirectory manually.  Similarly you may need other plugins from imageformats, etc. depending on your program.

Comment: @chappjc Your fix worked for me.  I find it very odd that the missing DLL isn't detected or traceable via something like dependency walker.  I find it equally odd that the same error message is solved by adding so many different DLL files depending on the project.  Anyhow, thanks to you both for the answer to my problem.  I guess the next thing is to figure out how to trace this a bit more easily or at least get the Qt owners to address and fix this.

Comment: @soulsabr I agree that it's strange that Dependency Walker couldn't identify this.

Comment: How did you get the qwindows.lib and Qt5PlatformSupport.lib to build? I'm building with -static but they do not build. It seems qwindows platform requirers direct X?

Answer (score 31):

For dynamic build only: Make sure you move the qwindows.dll to the following directory:

```
yourapp.exe
Qt5Core.dll
...
platforms/qwindows.dll
...
```

Note that the plugins directory is missing! You put all the needed folders from QT_BASE/.../plugins/* directly together with your binaries.
BTW: I did not need libEGL.dll, but my application almost has no GUI.

My source: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27056/#122588

Comment: Worked for me too. It would be nice to know how to let this deployment step working in CMake > 3.

Comment: Thanks, I was copying by mistake only the dlls. I needed to copy the folder  structure...

Comment: only this answer works for me, to add a folder: platforms/qwindows.dll , it contains this .dll; then everything is ok for the qt app.

Comment: Is there a way to cut off this 'platform integration' feature? QT4 did not require it. Why is it mandatory in QT5?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error with MinGW version of Qt (not static): "Failed to load platform plugin windows".

The solution for me was to add the DLLs `libEGL.dll` and `libEGLd.dll`.

Comment: That did it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495620/qt-5-1-1-application-failed-to-start-because-platform-plugin-windows-is-missi THANKS!

Answer (score 9):

You could also make an environment variable:

`QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=<QT_BASE>\plugins\platforms`

which in my case becomes:
  `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=f:\Qt\5\5.4\msvc2013_opengl\plugins\platforms`

Thus avoiding installing/copying `qwindows.dll` during development (to save disk-space!?).

This solution was also mentioned [on GitHub](https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5/issues/2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37918282/109941).

EDIT: Sorry, this is not effective in a static build. But I'll leave my *A* here.

Comment: Extra love for offering an non invasive answer.

Comment: +1. In my case `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=<top qt directory>/5.9.8/gcc_64/plugins/`, so one level up, was sufficient. Please take note that I found this solution applicable to a Linux environment as well

Comment: +1. Understanding where the platform data is located furthered my understanding to the point where I could get WebGL to run.

Answer (score 6):

Ok I had similar issue.

I found out that QT 5.2+ has windeployq.exe

> QT_DIRECTORY\5.2...\bin\windeployq.exe

Use it with the directory of your project (where the .exe of your application is). And voilà ! Automatically linked everything and ready to deploy !

It will get the DLLs, Plugins etc... automatically !

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Together with this link : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is to copy the `qtbase/plugins/platforms` directory into the Debug/Release directories leaving just `qwindowsd.dll` or `qwindows.dll` as appropriate.

Comment: This is a static build. No DLL's, just a single exe file.

Comment: Ah I see. Hopefully this is useful to others who are using dlls.

Comment: Yes, you almost right, but you have to put the "qwindowsd.dll" from "QtBase\plugins\platforms" to the "platforms\qwindowsd.dll" folder as adler said. Don't forget about relative path!

Answer (score 2):

Starting with QT 5.9+ *Qt5PlatformSupport.lib* is no longer available and has been [split](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/ea913750b8793e1e) into different libraries.
To create a static build under windows one needs to link the following additional libraries:

```
Qt5FontDatabaseSupport.lib
Qt5EventDispatcherSupport.lib
Qt5ThemeSupport.lib
Qt5PlatformCompositorSupport.lib
Qt5AccessibilitySupport.lib
Qt5WindowsUiAutomationSupport.lib
qwindows.lib
```

and load the windows plugin [statically](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtplugin.html#Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN):

```
#include <QtPlugin>
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN (QWindowsIntegrationPlugin);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions is,if you are using anaconda and python to make a gui using qt designer then go to anaconda,pkgs,qt.xxx,library,plugins ,then copy the platforms folder to your build folder wich contains your program.exe

Answer (score 0):

I exactly this probelm. The solution is to check the Qt in Debug output. That window tells you all the DLLs it loads. These are the ones you may need  in your distribution exe folder.

Comment: This is a static build. No DLL's, just a single exe file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with VS2015 and the version of Qt 5.9.3

I solved the error by replacing the Qt5Cored.dll and Qt5Core.dll(where the exe of my application) with the same DLLs in Qt directory