# Qt example projects don't run

Tags: c++, qt

I recently downloaded QT and am attempting to familiarize myself with it. However, I cannot get the example projects to run! When I try to run one of the examples, it exits with a message such as this:

```
Starting C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.4\build-gui-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\rasterwindow\debug\rasterwindow.exe...
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".

Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.4\build-gui-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\rasterwindow\debug\rasterwindow.exe exited with code 3
```

I have seen several questions about this error, but all of them are using Visual Studio. I am just using the default QT editor, and have made no changes to the example project. Additionally, when I try write a basic application that will simply create a window, it runs with no error message but no window is created. I can still write a "hello world" program that uses cout but QT won't create a widget window.

I am on Windows 7 32 bit, using default Qt editor. Did I skip some important step during installation? I just ran the installer executable.

Comment: are you trying to start the `.exe` in that folder? or does that happen when you run the project out of QtCreator?

Comment: @deW1 When I run it from QtCreator

Comment: Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen. there should be windows as well O.o so it looks like you're missing the windows platform plugin. I would reinstall it http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/

Comment: Did you build Qt yourself? What is the exact URL of the file you downloaded and installed Qt from?

Comment: @KubaOber I downloaded it from http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt5 Static Build yields Failed to load platform plugin "windows"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773789/qt5-static-build-yields-failed-to-load-platform-plugin-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the program can't find qwindows.dll.

You should check `qwindows.dll` in `platforms` directory.

`.../platforms/qwindows.dll`

Comment: qwindows.dll exists in the directories C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\plugins\platforms and C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\plugins\platforms. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's in `C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\plugins\platforms` directory. Have you solved this problem?